# Как правильно делать авторизацию на Яндекс Деньги на PHP?

Tags: php

Всем привет. Передо мной стоит задача получать историю операций с моего кошелька Яндекс.Деньги. Клиент должен перевести деньги с определенным комментарием, а скрипт на PHP должен проверить, пришли ли деньги на мой кошелек.
1. Я зарегистрировал приложение тут https://money.yandex.ru/myservices/new.xml, сохранил client_id
Далее, как говорят разработчики, нужно отправить запрос на авторизацию

Я делаю запрос и мне яндекс выдает ответ "войдите под своим аккаунтом, чтобы выдать доступ к истории платежей. То есть, как они задумали, надо отправить запрос через , чтобы страница яндекса открылась в новой вкладке.
А мне нужно получить код, потом получить токен (как пишут разрабы), а потом уже делать запрос на историю платежей.
Я захожу сюда (выпуск токена) https://tech.yandex.ru/money/doc/dg/reference/obtain-access-token-docpage/ и тут нужно в POST вставить параметр code, который надо получить с помощью авторизации. Кто имел опыт с яндекс деньгами, подскажите, как мне получить код авторизаци?

Comment: Вот страница с действиями для запроса авторизации https://tech.yandex.ru/money/doc/dg/reference/request-access-token-docpage/, а что у вас в коде происходит - расскажет только телепат.

Comment: Я и делаю запрос на /oauth/authorize, но яндекс показывает хтмл страничку "войдите в аккаунт", да и в конце страницы в документации написано, что будет редирект на result url, а мне нужно через php скрипт получить код, а затем токен, попробуйте сами сделать запрос через postman, увидите, что там результат не json, какой-то другой запрос надо использовать, видимо